# Child View Controller to Rotate While Parent View Controller Does Not

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, landscape-portrait, childviewcontroller

**What I am Trying to Do:**

Parent View that is managed by Parent View Controller ***SHOULD NOT ROTATE***.

Child View that is managed by Child View Controller ***SHOULD ROTATE*** to all orientations.

---

[image]

[image]

---

**What I Have Tried:**

ParentViewController

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Portrait
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

fun addChildViewController() {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.childViewController = storyBoard("Child View Controller") as? ChildViewController
    self .addChildViewController(self.childViewController!)
    self.childViewController! .didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.view .addSubview(self.childViewController!.view)
    self.childViewController!.view.frame = CGRectMake (40, 200, 400, 250)
}
```

ChildViewController

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return  .All
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Supported orientations in Xcode Deployment Info are set to all four.

**What I Get:**

None of the View's rotate.  If I set the parent's rotation to all, all views rotate together.  So it's all or nothing.

---

UPDATE

When I try putting an observer for **UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification** and use UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation to rotate *childView* using CGAffaineTransformMakeRotate , I get desired results.  HOWEVER, i.e., if I rotate to landscape, and try to pull down the notification center (or if I get a system notification), which is still in the portrait orientation (because the app is natively still left in Portrait), rotated *childView* rotates back to portrait to honor the status bar/notification/notification center.

**Stock iOS Camera App** is the best example I can present.  The main canvas does not rotate in to different orientations, yet the status bar, behind the scenes, rotates honoring device rotation.  Also the subviews rotate within them selves to honor different orientations.  I am trying to achieve this behavior....

Comment: Not sure if this would work, take it just as an idea. I would definitely set the app to support only one (portrait) orientation, and then I would try to detect the rotation of the device (not the screen) and respond to that by manually rotating the view in the middle of the screen. I guess  `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` would not work, so you'll need to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: You mean rotate using something like CGAffineTransform?

Comment: Yes, exactly CGAffineTransform. You have an interesting situation. Would love to help and actually try to write some code to address this issue, but I'm afraid I'll be quiet busy, so I won't be able to get my hands dirty here.

Comment: Well, I was leaving CGAffineTransform rotate method as a plan Z.  I am surprised how above code doesn't work.  It just doesn't pass 'shouldAutorotate()' up the view controllers.

Comment: Updated the OP mentioning the problem with that route...

Comment: Does the rotating ViewController have to be a child of the non-rotating ViewController? If it wasn't a child, you could just have two separate view controllers, similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14408563/854730)

Comment: Note that, due to changes in the underlying implementation of autorotation in iOS 8, adding subviews to the application's window may no longer be an effective technique: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many back and forth's with Apple them selves, and them pointing to the same link [Technical Q&A QA1890](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html), I had to do this with the flowing way:

MotherViewController

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({(context: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
            let deltaTransform: CGAffineTransform = coordinator.targetTransform()
            let deltaAngle: CGFloat = atan2(deltaTransform.b, deltaTransform.a)
            var currentRotation: CGFloat = self.mainView.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z") as! CGFloat

            // Adding a small value to the rotation angle forces the animation to occur in a the desired direction, preventing an issue where the view would appear to rotate 2PI radians during a rotation from LandscapeRight -> LandscapeLeft.
            currentRotation += -1 * deltaAngle + 0.0001
            self.mainView.layer.setValue(currentRotation, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.z")

            }, completion: {(
                context: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
                // Integralize the transform to undo the extra 0.0001 added to the rotation angle.
                var currentTransform: CGAffineTransform = self.mainView.transform
                currentTransform.a = round(currentTransform.a)
                currentTransform.b = round(currentTransform.b)
                currentTransform.c = round(currentTransform.c)
                currentTransform.d = round(currentTransform.d)
                self.mainView.transform = currentTransform
        })
    }
```

MainViewController

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "orientationChanged:", name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func orientationChanged ( notification: NSNotification){
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
        case .Portrait:
            self.rotateChildViewsForOrientation(0)
        case .PortraitUpsideDown:
            self.rotateChildViewsForOrientation(0)
        case .LandscapeLeft:
            self.rotateChildViewsForOrientation(90)
        case .LandscapeRight:
            self.rotateChildViewsForOrientation(-90)
        default:
            print ("Default")
                }
    }
```

---

This seem to rotate the child view's while keeping the main view static.  Also the app seem to know the proper orientation when notifications come in (because mother view actually rotates behind the scenes).

Special thanks to **jamesk** and **Warif Akhand Rishi** for all the help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778355/why-am-i-seeing-a-glitch-in-the-counter-rotation-animation Any idea why?

Comment: can you elaborate on this answer? what is rotateChildViewsForOrientation? There's no declaration of the function

Answer (score 13):

The effect achieved in the Camera app is similar to using a combination of:

- the technique described in [Technical Q&A QA1890](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html) for preventing a view from rotating; and
- the use of child UIStackViews to rearrange subviews on device rotation (see, e.g., the [SimpleExampleViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AdaptiveElements/Listings/AdaptiveElements_SimpleExampleViewController_swift.html) class in the [AdaptiveElements](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AdaptiveElements) sample code shown in [WWDC 2016 Session 233](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/233/)).

The technical note explains that the underlying implementation of autorotation involves applying a transform directly to the application's window:

> Autorotation is implemented by applying a rotation transform to the application's window when the system determines that the interface must rotate. The window then adjusts its bounds for the new orientation and propagates this change down through the view controller hierarchy via calls to each view controller's and presentation controller's `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method.

Note that the Camera app does **not** opt out of autorotation: when using the Camera app, the orientations of Notification Center and Control Center reflect the device orientation. It is only particular views within the Camera app that appear to opt out of autorotation. In fact, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30394124/5352503) suggests that such apps typically utilise the `videoGravity` and `videoOrientation` properties provided by AVFoundation classes such as [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer/videoGravity) and [AVCaptureConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureConnection/videoOrientation).

The approach you should take depends on whether you only want to stop a parent view from rotating or whether you want to stop a container view controller such as UINavigationController from rotating (i.e. lock device orientation).

If the former, use the technique described in the technical note to fix the orientation of the parent view, and (for iOS 9) wrap rotating subviews in a UIStackView and use the `axis` property to rearrange the subviews on device rotation, or (for iOS 8) manually rotate the subviews on device rotation (as to which see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28570127/5352503) and [this sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25775460/5352503)).

If the latter, the approach you're taking is on the right track. For sample code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108451/5352503). You'll need to share your code and more information about your view controller hierarchy for us to diagnose quirks involving Notification Center.

**Addendum**: The reason why calls to `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` were not being propagated to child view controllers was explained in [Technical Q&A QA1688](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1688/_index.html):

> Beginning with iOS 6, only the topmost view controller (alongside the `UIApplication` object) participates in deciding whether to rotate in response to a change of the device's orientation. More often than not, the view controller displaying your content is a child of `UINavigationController`, `UITabBarController`, or a custom container view controller. You may find yourself needing to subclass a container view controller in order to modify the values returned by its `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.

In Swift, you can [override those methods by using extensions](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html).

Comment: Great reply! I am still reading the links.  As I mentioned below, I am having issues using viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: because I want the motherView to NOT rotate while childView to rotate.  If motherView does not rotate at all, viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: would not be called within it self.

Comment: Here's the trick: don't return `false` from `shouldAutorotate`. Use the technique shown in the technical note to prevent motherView from rotating—which won't interfere with `viewWillTransitionToSize:`—and use the latter (or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`) to rotate your subviews accordingly.

Comment: Let us help! What's misbehaving?

Comment: Well, your links were extremely helpful. I know this is achievable using stackView's & Autolayout; However, viewWillTransitionToSize: method seems keep things cleaner for this particular project.

Comment: Going back to the beginning: I want to keep the mainView static while the childView rotates. After all that, when a notification comes in, the status bar has to be in the proper orientation.  Referring to iOS Camera App, Main interface stays still, flash icon rotates.  I need the exact behavior.  If were to use viewWillTransitionToSize: method, to how can I use it inside mainViewController, if thats the view I am trying to stop from rotating? Also, I DO want the childView to rotate.

Comment: So far, I came to a complicated method using viewWillTransitionToSize: and  UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation with UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification KVO.  Use viewWillTransitionToSize: to stop rotating the mainView.  use UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation with UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification KVO to rotate the childView using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Comment: Is the issue with that method the same as what you described in the OP—about the child view resetting its rotation when you access Notification Center? Are you overriding `shouldAutorotate` with this solution?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778355/why-am-i-seeing-a-glitch-in-the-counter-rotation-animation Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

From iOS developer library [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html#top)

> Autorotation is implemented by applying a rotation transform to the application's window when the system determines that the interface must rotate. The window then adjusts its bounds for the new orientation and propagates this change down through the view controller hierarchy via calls to each view controller's and presentation controller's -viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. Invocations of this method are provided a transition coordinator object containing the delta of the window's current transform and new transform, which can be retrieved by sending a -targetTransform message to the transition coordinator. Your view controller or presentation controller can derive the appropriate inverse transform and apply it to the target view. This nullifies the effect of the window transform on that particular view and gives the appearance that the view has remained fixed in its current orientation as the rest of the interface rotates normally.

i.e. if you have a view named `noRotatingView`

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    noRotatingView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds))
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

        let deltaTransform = coordinator.targetTransform()
        let deltaAngle = atan2f(Float(deltaTransform.b), Float(deltaTransform.a))

        var currentRotation = self.noRotatingView.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z")?.floatValue

        // Adding a small value to the rotation angle forces the animation to occur in a the desired direction, preventing an issue where the view would appear to rotate 2PI radians during a rotation from LandscapeRight -> LandscapeLeft.
        currentRotation = currentRotation! + (-1 * Float(deltaAngle)) + 0.0001
        self.noRotatingView.layer.setValue(currentRotation, forKeyPath:"transform.rotation.z")

        }) { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

            var currentTransform = self.noRotatingView.transform;
            currentTransform.a = round(currentTransform.a);
            currentTransform.b = round(currentTransform.b);
            currentTransform.c = round(currentTransform.c);
            currentTransform.d = round(currentTransform.d);
            self.noRotatingView.transform = currentTransform;
    }
}
```

I've tried to make a demo project at https://github.com/rishi420/TestCameraRotation

Comment: Great job with your answer!  Looking at your sample code, I keep coming to the main issue I am still having even when I was looking at Apple's Technical documentation for this: MotherView does not rotate, ChildView rotates. viewWillTransitionToSize method would not be called if the containing view does not rotate at all.  This is where I am still stuck...

Comment: @gizmodo I think mother view rotates in iOS camera app. coz notification center and control center rotates. If you want to lock the mother view you can see [RotateButton](https://github.com/rishi420/RotateButton).

Comment: Combination of your TestCameraRotation + RotateButton makes the best sense at this point. 1. Put MainView inside another view and use viewWillTransitionToSize to stop it from rotating. 1. Use device orientation KVO to rotate childView.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778355/why-am-i-seeing-a-glitch-in-the-counter-rotation-animation Any idea why? @Gizmodo